# Is the update in this MERGE Statement redundant?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, t-sql, merge

I'm trying improve the performance of a complicated stored procedure. Inside the stored procedure is the following `MERGE` statement. I'm not very familiar with the `MERGE` syntax.

The `[Contact].[PhoneNumber]` table looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE [Contact].[PhoneNumber]
(
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    [PhoneNumber] [nvarchar](255) NOT NULL
    [InsertedAtDateTimeUTC] [datetime2](7) NOT NULL DEFAULT(sysutcdatetime())
)
```

The merge looks like this:

```
;WITH _ContactPhoneNumbers ([PhoneNumber]) AS 
(
    SELECT DISTINCT ([#ChannelData].[CallerAni])
    FROM [#ChannelData]
)
MERGE [Contact].[PhoneNumber] WITH (HOLDLOCK) _target
USING [_ContactPhoneNumbers] _source ON [_target].[PhoneNumber] = [_source].[PhoneNumber]

WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
    INSERT ([PhoneNumber])
    VALUES ([PhoneNumber])

WHEN MATCHED THEN
    UPDATE 
        SET [_target].[PhoneNumber] = [_source].[PhoneNumber]
        OUTPUT INSERTED.[Id], [_source].[PhoneNumber] INTO #Contact_PhoneNumber_Output ([Id], [PhoneNumber]);
```

I read this as:

If the `PhoneNumber` does not exist in the `[Contact].[PhoneNumber]` table the merge inserts a new row into the `[Contact].[PhoneNumber]` and returns the new `Id`. If `PhoneNumber` does exist then the merge *updates the `PhoneNumber` to be the same value*, and returns the `Id` for the existing row.

Is the `UPDATE` redundant?

If it's redundant I'll take it out and see if it increases the performance. There are several `MERGE` statements in the stored procedure which follows the same pattern (with the `UPDATE`) so it could be a useful gain.

The `Id` is returned even if it exists, as it's used as an FK in a further insert.

Comment: The `WHEN MATCHED .. UPDATE` seems redundant but you could have tried it ;) You could do the same thing with a much simple `INSERT .. WHERE NOT EXISTS` or an `INSERT .. SELECT ... EXCEPT ..`

Comment: `[PhoneNumber]` in `VALUES ( [PhoneNumber] )` needs to be qualified, because both `_source` and `_target` have got a column by that name.

Answer (score 5):

Something needs to be in the `WHEN MATCHED THEN` clause, otherwise you don't get the `Id` back when the row exists.

However, [you don't need to update the target table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5316669/update-no-op-in-sql-merge-statement).

```
DECLARE @dummy int;

;WITH    _ContactPhoneNumbers ( [PhoneNumber] )
              AS ( SELECT    DISTINCT
                            ( [#ChannelData].[CallerAni] )

                   FROM     [#ChannelData]
                 )
        MERGE [PhoneNumber]  WITH ( HOLDLOCK ) _target
        USING [_ContactPhoneNumbers] _source
        ON [_target].[PhoneNumber] = [_source].[PhoneNumber]
        WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
            INSERT ( [PhoneNumber] )
            VALUES ([PhoneNumber] )
        WHEN MATCHED THEN
            UPDATE SET @dummy = 0
        OUTPUT
            INSERTED.[Id] ,                
            [_source].[PhoneNumber]
        INTO #Contact_PhoneNumber_Output ( [Id], [PhoneNumber] );
```

Given the information in [Use Caution with SQL Server's MERGE Statement](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3074/use-caution-with-sql-servers-merge-statement/), I'm going to ditch the `MERGE` completely. There's loads of `LCK_M_RS_U` contention too so I think I'll be better off with simpler SQL which I understand better.